# My pygame rects are giving a rect argument is invalid error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've been looking for a solution for this error for about 15 minutes now and no posts or other websites covered the specific error i've been having.
Here's the code snippet in question:

```
import pygame
win = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))
width = 10
height = 40
pipex = 10
pipe1y = 10
pipe1 = pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 255, 100), (width, height1))
pygame.win.blit(pipe1, pipex, pipe1y)
pygame.display.update()
```

And here's the full code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
from bird import brd
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((400,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Bird')


pipex = 345
pipe1y = -270
pipe2y = 420
width = 65
height1 = 400
height2 = 3000

vel = 5
bird_x = 20
bird_y = 300
isJump = 0
jumpCount = 0

yy = 0
class fb:
    def move():
        global pipex
        global yy
        global pipe1y
        global pipe2y
        global bird_x
        global bird_y
        pipex -= 1
        if pipex < -60:
            pipex = 345
            yy = random.randint(-350,0)
            pipe1y = yy
            pipe2y = pipe1y + 555
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,0,0), (0,0,1000,1000))
        pipe1 = pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 255, 100), (width, height1))
        pipe2 = pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 255, 0), (width, height2))
        bird = pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(30, 30))
        pygame.win.blit(pipe1, pipex, pipe1y)
        pygame.win.blit(pipe2, pipex, pipe2y)
        pygame.win.blit(bird, bird_x, bird_y)
        pygame.display.update()
        bird_y += 2
    def gameover():
        pygame.quit()
    def checks():
        global yy
        global bird_x
        global bird_y
        global pipex
        if bird_y > 600:
            fb.gameover()
        
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bird_y -= 4
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        bird_y += 1
    fb.move()
    time.sleep(0.005)
    fb.checks()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break
```

I need the rects to be objects or variables so i can check for collision later down the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument of [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) defines the rectangular which is filled by the color. It is a tuple with 4 components (*x*, *y*, *width*, *height*). (*x*, *y*) defien the top left corner of the rectangle and (*width*, *height*) defines the size of the rectangle.

In your case (`pipex`, `pipe1y`) seem to be the position of the rectnagle:

<s>`pipe1 = pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 255, 100), (width, height1))`</s>

```py
pipe1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 100), (pipex, pipe1y, width, height1))
```

Comment: `TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect`

this error arose after your fix, do you have any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: @7abc778 Th 1st argument t [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) is a Surface (image): `pygame.win.blit(your_image, pipe1)`. You have to substitute `your_image` by the image (Surface) that you want to blit. Most likely you don't need this line of code, because `pygame.draw.rect` already draws a rectangle to the screen.